# doinbackground not waiting for oncallback

Tags: android, arcgis

I am using the asyncclass to submit edits. The doinbackground() method calls an applyedits() method which calls an addattachment() method. both the addattachment() and applyedits() methods have oncallbacks. the doinbackground() method doesn't seem to wait for the oncallbacks.

how can i make doinbackground() wait for the results from the other two methods?

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot do anything asynchronous from `doInBackground()`.

Comment: i can't post the code.

Comment: are you suggesting that i should be running my async tasks from the UI thread, CommonWare?

Comment: no, he suggets that addattachment() and applyedits() methods should be  synchronous or called before doInBackground in UI thread.